# How to dynamically set the row value reference in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

My question is, how to set the row value dynamically in a conditional formatting formula, i.e.

=D$**1**=0

where the 1 has to be replaced dynamically with a value hold in a specific cell (first column = $A and related row = 8)

Example: Assume a number of employees with a distinct ID, a range of cells to be conditionally formatted according to true or false entries in another range associated to the employees IDs. The column part of the reference in the written formula is fix (the column to be formatted). The row value is fix too. The employees name depends on the ID and inserted by VLOOKUP. Each field in the to be formatted range is representing a task to do. When I now have to assign a task to a different employee I can simple change the ID in front of the name and via VLOOKUP a new employees name will appear. Unfortunately the conditional formatting has to be customized in addition because the row number is not dynamic. 5 Employees means I have 5 conditional formatting formulas.

What I want is: Only one conditional formula

D8 has to be yellow when D1 is '0' (ID is 1 = Alex). I now change A8 to ID 5 = Mark. D8 has to change to white because D5 is '1' The ID has to be the row part of the formula.

The column part is fix 'D' but the row part has to be the number of the ID dynamically.

Sample excel screenshot:

[image]

How to solve this problem? Hope the question is not only confusing and maybe helps to build more flexible excel sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an INDEX formula for this purpose:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$H$5,MATCH($A8,$C$1:$C$5,0),COLUMN()-3)=0
```

Comment: This will work so long as the sequence remains unchanged. If I change A8 to 5 (Mark), the formula has to change to D5 instead D1 as the underlying formatting value for row 8 (D8 - H8). That is what I meant with dynamic row part of Dx

Comment: Oh right sorry I didn't undertand exactly what you menat - hang on i'll change my answer

Comment: the approach was worth a try but it didn´t work for my needs because although it is possible to get the ID of an employee, even in case of multiple occurences of one and the same employee - Excel seems to have a problem with composed cell references in cond. formatting, because I do not know how to set the column, i.e. D:

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem, never found it without the index hint from maxhob17.

1. =INDEX(D$1:D$5;$A8)=0     as the formatting formula placed in cell D8

   That means search matrix D1 to D5 in row given through ID in A8
2. =$D$8:$H$12               that formula will be applied to that area

   The rest is done by excel itself. Be aware of relative and absolute cell
   references